# optimize loading of a select - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Good morning, I have a select that loads a large number of records but when mounting the select to my project it becomes slow because it loads a large number of records, how do I optimize my select so it doesn't become slow? I've tried to improve the load but it did not succeed, if someone could help me I would appreciate it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-jerry-3ug31u?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [carrera, setCarrera] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getcountry3 = async () => {
      const req = await fetch(
        "https://witalenco.com.co/apiWittytalent/dyc/titulos/carreras.php"
      );
      const getres3 = await req.json();
      console.log(getres3);
      setCarrera(await getres3);
    };
    getcountry3();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <select name="carrera" className="form-select">
        <option>--Seleccione --</option>
        {carrera.map((getcon3) => (
          <option key={getcon3.id_titulos} value={getcon3.id_titulos}>
            {" "}
            {getcon3.carrera}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It better to use pagination on API

Comment: 1. make the fetch request once  on the load of the application - not on a reload of the component in the useEffect. Assign it to the window object or something, and check it exists rather than re-request it

Comment: 2. remove the console.log - that will slow it down

Comment: 3. flatten the object so you don't have to do a lookup - instead of careera.map(getcon3 => getcon3.carera  - make it so you can do  careera.map(result => result

Comment: 4. limit the output so you only load max 1000 items or something, and then lazy load the rest in the background

Comment: but how would it be since I have tried but I have not been able to do it, can you help me?